# Trying to compare two Canvas elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I am using below code to compare two canvas elements

```
function createImage(html, can) {
     var canvas = $( "#" + can );
     var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
     var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1000' height='1000'>" +
                    "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
                        "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
                            html +
                        "</div>" +
                    "</foreignObject>" +
                "</svg>";
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = '';
    var svg = new Blob([data], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
    img.src = url;
    //return img.src;
    return canvas[0];
}
var a1 = createImage("<span style='font-size:34px'><i><b>Hello</b></i></span>","can1");
var a2 = createImage("<span style='font-size:34px'><i><b>Hello</b></i></span>", "can2");
setTimeout(function() {
    var ctx1 = a1.getContext('2d');
    var imageData = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, a1.width, a1.height);
    var pixels = imageData.data;
    var ctx2 = a2.getContext('2d');
    var imageData2 = ctx2.getImageData(0, 0, a2.width, a2.height);
    var pixels2 = imageData2.data, count;
    for(var i = 0, il = pixels.length; i < il; i++) {
        if(pixels[i] == pixels2[i]){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count === pixels.length && count === pixels2.length){
        alert("Match");
    }
},5000);
```

But it is returning me error like below

> Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Your canvas is being populated (at least in part) by a different domain to where your script is running - thus you can't read it as it would allow data to leack across the domain boundary, vuilating the same origin policy. The only way to avoid this is make sure all the scripts are running on the same domain

Comment: @Basic Actually I am comparing these two Canvas elements from Content Script of Chrome extension.. Even in localhost I can see the same problem..

Comment: Hmmmm interesting - it wouldn't surprise me if Chrome extensions have some quirks around how the security model is applied but I'm afraid I can't help your further - Hopefully someone else will be able to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you get a cross-origin error is because of the use of `<svg>` with namespace declarations located at `http://www.w3.org/`, which is of a different origin:

```
var data = "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='1000' height='1000'>" +
             "<foreignObject width='100%' height='100%'>" +
               "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
                    html +
               "</div>" +
             "</foreignObject>" +
           "</svg>";
```

I can tell this method is the one from [Drawing DOM objects into a canvas on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas).

When you re-access the data this way,

```
var ctx1 = a1.getContext('2d');
var imageData = ctx1.getImageData(0, 0, a1.width, a1.height);
```

you will hit the error:

> Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

You can test this on Chrome:

- [Your original version](http://jsfiddle.net/wW4Qg/) with the error
- [Another version with namespace declarations removed](http://jsfiddle.net/wW4Qg/1/), which does not throw an error and is at the same time blank due to the absence of namespace declarations

You can only return the data from the function to avoid getting this error. But because of the asynchronous nature of `img.onload`,

```
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};
```

you have to defer the retrieval of data, forcing you to re-access the data out of the function and causing the error.

Thus, you should use an alternate method of building the canvas with DOM objects that does not rely on `<svg>`, like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com).

```
function createImage(html) {
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    var el = document.createElement("div");
        el.innerHTML = html;
        el.style.display = 'inline-block';
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    html2canvas(el, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
          document.body.appendChild(canvas);
          document.body.removeChild(el);
          dfd.resolve(canvas.toDataURL());
      }
    });
    return dfd;
}
$.when(
    createImage("<span style='font-size:34px'><i><b>Hello</b></i></span>"), 
    createImage("<span style='font-size:34px'><i><b>Hello</b></i></span>")
).done(function(a1, a2){
   if (a1 === a2) {
      alert("Match"); 
   }
});
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X9t74/).

Comment: Good catch. I couldn't understand why it only affected a few browsers and only SVG files...

Answer (score 1):

### About the "cross origin policy" problems

> Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
>   SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

It's a security issue caused by the navigator "*cross origin policy*".

---

This error will appear if you have "dirtied" your canvas. This is done by drawing images to the canvas that are from a different origin. For instance, if your canvas is hosted at www.example.com, and you use images from www.wikipedia.org, then your canvas `origin-clean` flag is set to `false` internally.

Once the origin-clean flag is set to `false`, you are no longer allowed to call `toDataURL` or `getImageData`

---

Technically, images are of the same origin if domains, protocols, and ports match.

---

If you are working locally (file://) then any image drawn will set off the flag. This makes debugging annoying, but with Chrome you can start it with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files` to allow this.

---

To learn more read the article: "[Understanding the HTML5 Canvas image security rules](http://simonsarris.com/blog/480-understanding-the-html5-canvas-image-security-rules)".

Credits to [Simon Sarris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154112/simon-sarris)

### My files are in the same domain or the chrome flag is activated and I still get this error, what's happening?

The problem is that Chrome (currently) always taints a canvas when an SVG document is drawn to it.

For a more detailed explanation see the question below:

**[Rasterizing an in-document SVG to Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8158312/rasterizing-an-in-document-svg-to-canvas)**

### Ok, the use of svg seems to be the problem, so how to fix it?

At the time of my writing Antony answered it!

[**See his answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16488779/2252829).

Comment: You describe here reason but not an answer. Sadly `--allow-file-access-from-files` is not an answer that can be valid to develop chrome-extensions. Or would you write in Chrome Web Store *to use this extension please run your chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files*?

Comment: @walery The `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag is useful in development environment. If your extension needs to use files in client machine probably ask for user to start with that flag is not a good practice. The main point of the question is keep your files, like images, in the same domain to avoid dirt in the origin-clean flag. If the extension needs to run offline, use the [appcache manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) to   download needed files in the client machine.

Comment: Did you read the question? There are no files somewhere online. Everything is inside of extension. So using appcache is not necessary. Problem is that on this place `img.src = url;` the origin-clean flag is set to DIRTY. And the question is: how to avoid this.

Comment: @walery Thank you for call my attention. Because of that I've learned a bit.