# Rendering of SVG as canvas pattern in Chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, design-patterns, canvas, svg

Well that's about it, I use an SVG image to create a pattern. The pattern displays in most browsers. Chrome however doesn't display the pattern.
if I put a png image as the source of my new Image() object, Chrome displays it.
I was trying to find out if that was normal, but can't find anything about in on the web.
Am I doing something wrong or is that a known issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16337993/trying-to-compare-two-canvas-elements

Comment: Thank you Rob, but the topic you forwarded me seems to apply to security issues. but the svg file i am using is local...

Comment: Chrome considers `file://` as non-same-origin. Put it on localhost or some other server.

Comment: Still isn't working. The js and image file are on the same server.  I'm calling it directly as this :
        imageObj.src= "img/ceca_to_ue_graph/hatcheuro.svg"; should I call it like an absolute link?

Comment: I can use `new Image().src = 'demo.svg';` without any issues (except that it looks slightly different than what I created in Inkscape, call it a bug). My previous comment was referring to the use of svg on `<canvas>` elements. Is the `<canvas>` element really relevant to your question? If not, please edit the question and remove the `canvas` tag.

Comment: My question is relevant to canvas. When I use an image that is a local svg file(whether the folders are local or hosted on a server, I've tested both) as a pattern IN a canvas element. The pattern will not display in Chrome. Has anyone ever encountered such issue? My code :>  <!-- language: lang-js --> var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
   var pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'repeat');
   drawGraph(firstYear, lastYear, totalRadius, pattern);                   
        }
imageObj.src= "img/ceca_to_ue_graph/hatcheuro.svg";

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found for the same problem in Chrome is to include the patterns inside the svg in base64 encoding:

```
<pattern  id="pat01" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...CC " style="opacity:1;stop-opacity:1" /></pattern>
...
<circle cx="23" cy="153" r="18" style="opacity:1;fill:url(#pat01);fill-opacity:1;stop-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit: 10;"></circle>
```

When you serialize it and paint in a canvas, the patterns are displayed properly.